# Nullpointer Exception "void android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri)"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, nullpointerexception, mediastore

I'm trying to take a music file from the music folder of the user in a **Fragment**, but when I do that and after receiving it in onActivityResult (and logging it), I get a Nullpointer Exception when I want to play it with media player.
The code to pick the file:

```
    Button pickFile = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnpick);
    pickFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
```

OnActivityResult (Don't forgetting that I'm in a fragment)

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
  getActivity();
  if ((resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) && (data != null)) {
  Log.d("result", "okreceived");
  Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(data.getData().toString());
  Log.i("result", "Intent data " + data.getData().toString());
  mplayergo(soundUri);
       }
  if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED)
  {
  //null
  }
        }

       public void mplayergo(Uri soundUri){
           try {
               mplayer.setDataSource(getActivity(), soundUri);
               mplayer.start();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }
```

Here's the log:

> D/result: okreceived I/result: Intent data
>   content://media/external/audio/media/34839 W/System.err:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(android.content.Context,
>   android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference at
>   com.package.example.GameFragment.mplayergo(GameFragment.java:764)  at
>   com.package.example.GameFragment.onActivityResult(GameFragment.java:748)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:156)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6290)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3606)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3653)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1371)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5300)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)

Solved by re-initializing MediaPlayer and setting the URI as a source.

```
 public void mplayergo(Uri soundUri){
       try {
           mplayer.stop();
           mplayer.reset();
           mplayer.release();
           mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), soundUri);
          // mplayer.start();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Comment: have you initialized your MediaPlayer  class?

Comment: Yes, It's Already initialized and it works well in the fragment except here,  or Maybe I have to initialize it another time because I'm modifying the stream?

Comment: then check for getActivity() it is null i think.

Comment: Oooh yes, I have to re-initialize it, solved :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mplayer` is not initialized. So when you try to invoke the method `setDataSource` it gets null pointer exception. Try to initialize `mplayer` before invoking that method.

Comment: Yes, I had to re-initialize it and now it works, thank you :)